# Cannot determine your user name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Really need help here,

I made some mess into my `/etc/passwd` file, hoping that I can remove the user's password by removing its entry.

Upon saving it says `cannot find name for user ID 1000`. Now I can't do `sudo` or `su -` to access my superuser account because it always says `Cannot determine your user name`, I'm trying to edit the `/etc/passwd` again but unfortunately I don't have root access...

I'm stuck with an unknown user, and unfortunately I don't have any backup yet for the server.

Is this possible to be resolved without doing re-installation?

Any solution to fix this?

I badly needed this to be fixed..

Comment: Can you log in as root through TTY? Can you mount the drive in a different computer and edit it there?

Comment: I tried logging in using `root` and my account password for Digital Ocean. but it says `Login Incorrect`

Comment: Does Digital Ocean have a virtual terminal/TTY, emergency login, etc? That is where you would log in using root.

Comment: yes, that's what I did. `Access >> Launch Console`

Comment: I have never used Digital Ocean. Perhaps you can save the image, move the image to some sort of file bucket, then grab the files you need and stick them in a new build?

Comment: Rackspace will create a new root login with every new build, even from old image, but not sure if Digital Ocean does the same thing.

Comment: I really hope your Digital Ocean account password is never stored in any of the account's servers.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tips, unfortunately it will cost some $ doing any backup or snapshot in DO so I'm trying to prevent any extra charges atm because it's my client who's paying for it, I still have a last option to `Reset Root Password` which will send a password change form to my email, hopefully this will resolve everything...

Answer (score 4):

Boot the system off of a live CD, mount your root filesystem, fix whatever you did to the file, then reboot.

And going forward, never edit that file directly. Instead, use the `vipw` command, which will prevent saving syntax errors most of the time.

Comment: I tried to do `Mount Recovery Kernel` but it says that my current plan doesn't allow me to do so... By the way I'm on Digital Ocean

Comment: Talk with DO support then.